# Candlestick Charting using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am trying to follow a youtube video ([5:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crWLWZtJr1o)) on drawing candlestick plots from stock price data but it's not displaying correctly. I'm guessing it has to do with my dates being in epoch time in the file. Please help.  Data looks like this: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R16ci.png)

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
plt.style.use('default')

df1 = pd.read_csv('RBZ_formatted1.csv')

df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime']-((3600*1000)*5), unit='ms')
df1['datetime'] = df1['datetime'].map(mdates.date2num)

# Making the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))

# Convert raw mdates numbers to dates
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.xlabel('Date & Time')

# Make candlestick plot
candlestick_ohlc(ax, df1.values, width=0.8, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.8)
# ax.plot(df1['date2'], df1['close'])

plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Sample Data')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Data Example................

```
datetime open high low close
1579120440000 1.94 1.96 1.83
1579120500000 1.92 1.93 1.77
1579120560000 1.81 1.84 1.75
1579120620000 1.74 1.87 1.72
1579120680000 1.86 1.87 1.80
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting`width=200` to some smaller value?

Comment: @fredo124 con you post some input data to reproduce problem?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi i did originally, but i just re added it to my post.

Comment: @JohanC just tried it, it did not work

Comment: Can you please add the data as text, not as image

Comment: Please also include all `import` lines. Data + runnable code = [mcve].

Comment: @JohanC added a few lines of data

Comment: @Parfait included all import lines